# Sabre Web Services .NET API Examples that aren't MVC?

Tags: c#, web-services, sabre

This is pretty general, but I'm having a hell of a time figuring out how to consume some of the more complicated Sabre APIs.

I have built working .NET proxy classes in C# using the WSDL for the basic APIs (CreateSession, CloseSession) but for the more complicated APIs I have a really hard time parsing out the complicated XML schema to figure out which methods to call in my program.

Are there any other .NET resources/examples out there that aren't wrapped up in MVC like the [code example that Sabre posted on GitHub](https://github.com/SabreDevStudio/SACS-DotNet)?

I'm trying to figure out how to use APIs like OTA_AirPriceLLSRQ and TravelItineraryReadRQ.

Thanks in advance for any help!

Comment: There are no other sources, at least provided by Sabre that I know. Still, if the MVC that you are referring is correctly built you should only focus on the Models, as there should be almost no code in the Controller and the View should be just a view.
Is there any service that you are having special trouble with?

Comment: Thanks you! I've tried digging through the models provided but I get so lost; way they structure the code with multiple interfaces and Service Factories is beyond me. I'm looking for a very simple object based approach to allow me to instantiate a API call and then consume it's response. I'm sure the way they have structured the MVC app is far more efficient, but it's too complicated for my noob mind.

I feel like if I could find a few examples of the simple approach I could start to understand the proxy classes enough to implement my own classes for most of the APIs exposed by Sabre.

Comment: I totally understand you, I have faced the same situation. What service are you trying to call? I might have it and I can copy my class here

Comment: Thanks - it's great just to hear that someone else had the same issue.

Ideally I'd like to use the `TravelItineraryReadRQ` API, but that one is pretty complicated. I am mostly interested in the PNR info APIs that return information about a given PNR like `eTicketCouponLLSRQ` and/or the APIs that execute commands like 'AirTicketLLSRQ`

Any help you can offer would be AWESOME. I feel like I need to learn to walk before I run, but once I figure this stuff out I'll be able to implement mos of the APIs without much fuss.

Comment: Sorry for the delay, I totally forgot. You've probably solved it by now, anyway I've added a response with my example :)

Answer (score 1):

As I mentioned on the comments, you should not focus on the actual MVC wrapping, as you'll be mainly putting stuff in the Model, or actually you'll put this somewhere else and consume it in the model.

Anyway, just for you to have as example, here's a **VERY** generic BFM (BargianFinderMax) class. With this approach it's required to create an instance, and after calling the Execute method it stores the response in the instance.

I hope it helps.

```
using BargainFinderMaxRQv310Srvc;
using System;
using System.IO;

namespace ServicesMethods
{
    public class BFM_v310
    {
        private BargainFinderMaxService service;
        private OTA_AirLowFareSearchRQ request;
        public OTA_AirLowFareSearchRS response;

        public BFM_v310(string token, string pcc, string convId, string endpoint)
        {
            //MessageHeader
            MessageHeader mHeader = new MessageHeader();

            PartyId[] pId = { new PartyId() };
            pId[0].Value = "SWS";

            From from = new From();
            from.PartyId = pId;

            To to = new To();
            to.PartyId = pId;

            mHeader.Action = "BargainFinderMaxRQ";
            mHeader.Service = new Service()
            {
                Value = mHeader.Action
            };
            mHeader.ConversationId = convId;
            mHeader.CPAId = pcc;
            mHeader.From = from;
            mHeader.To = to;
            mHeader.MessageData = new MessageData()
            {
                Timestamp = DateTime.UtcNow.ToString()
            };

            //Security
            Security security = new Security();
            security.BinarySecurityToken = token;

            //Service
            service = new BargainFinderMaxService();
            service.MessageHeaderValue = mHeader;
            service.SecurityValue = security;
            service.SoapVersion = System.Web.Services.Protocols.SoapProtocolVersion.Soap11;
            service.Url = endpoint;

            createRequest(pcc);
        }

        private void createRequest(string pcc)
        {
            request = new BargainFinderMaxRQv310Srvc.OTA_AirLowFareSearchRQ();
            request.AvailableFlightsOnly = true;
            request.Version = "3.1.0";

            request.POS = new SourceType[1];
            SourceType source = new SourceType();

            source.PseudoCityCode = pcc;
            source.RequestorID = new UniqueID_Type();
            source.RequestorID.ID = "1";
            source.RequestorID.Type = "1";
            source.RequestorID.CompanyName = new CompanyNameType();
            source.RequestorID.CompanyName.Code = "TN";
            source.RequestorID.CompanyName.CodeContext = "Context";
            request.POS[0] = source;

            OTA_AirLowFareSearchRQOriginDestinationInformation originDestination = new OTA_AirLowFareSearchRQOriginDestinationInformation();
            originDestination.OriginLocation = new OriginDestinationInformationTypeOriginLocation();
            originDestination.OriginLocation.LocationCode = "BCN";
            originDestination.DestinationLocation = new OriginDestinationInformationTypeDestinationLocation();
            originDestination.DestinationLocation.LocationCode = "MAD";
            originDestination.ItemElementName = ItemChoiceType.DepartureDateTime;
            originDestination.Item = "2017-09-10T12:00:00";
            originDestination.RPH = "1";
            request.OriginDestinationInformation = new OTA_AirLowFareSearchRQOriginDestinationInformation[1] { originDestination };

            request.TravelerInfoSummary = new TravelerInfoSummaryType()
            {
                AirTravelerAvail = new TravelerInformationType[1]
            };
            request.TravelerInfoSummary.AirTravelerAvail[0] = new TravelerInformationType()
            {
                PassengerTypeQuantity = new PassengerTypeQuantityType[1]
            };
            PassengerTypeQuantityType passenger = new PassengerTypeQuantityType()
            {
                Quantity = "1",
                Code = "ADT"
            };
            request.TravelerInfoSummary.AirTravelerAvail[0].PassengerTypeQuantity[0] = passenger;

            request.TravelerInfoSummary.PriceRequestInformation = new PriceRequestInformationType();
            request.TravelerInfoSummary.PriceRequestInformation.CurrencyCode = "USD";
            //PriceRequestInformationTypeNegotiatedFareCode nego = new PriceRequestInformationTypeNegotiatedFareCode();
            //nego.Code = "ABC";
            //request.TravelerInfoSummary.PriceRequestInformation.Items = new object[1] { nego };
            request.TPA_Extensions = new OTA_AirLowFareSearchRQTPA_Extensions();
            request.TPA_Extensions.IntelliSellTransaction = new TransactionType();
            request.TPA_Extensions.IntelliSellTransaction.RequestType = new TransactionTypeRequestType();
            request.TPA_Extensions.IntelliSellTransaction.RequestType.Name = "50ITIN";


        }

        public bool Execute()
        {
            response = service.BargainFinderMaxRQ(request);

            return response.PricedItinCount > 0;
        }
    }

}
```

Comment: That is great! This is super helpful; thanks for taking the time.

If you're going to be at TTX this year let me know - I'll buy you a cocktail or six.

Comment: I was there last year, but regrettably I won't be there this year, but thanks for the sentiment! :)

Answer (score 0):

My advice is you should add separate models which are built based on Sabre models, and which flatten the whole structure.

For example, `TravelItineraryReadRS` is a quite complicated document. Using it properties in your program is a real "pain", because every time you need to remember the whole path that leads to to specific information (like, "what is passenger type for PersonName of NameNumber 01.01?").

I suggest you have dedicated model (let's name it `Reservation`), which have all information that you will need later in your application, extracted from `TravelItineraryReadRs`. 
In order to achieve this you need a dedicated converter which will make convert TravelItineraryReadRs model into Reservation model. Now, inside Reservation model you could have list of Passenger models, which have in on place all important information (NameNumber, PassengerType, SSR codes, etc).

This improves readability and as a bonus you decouple your application from Sabre (imagine, one day someone asks "can we switch from Sabre to Amadeus?" - if you use dedicated models the answer is "yes". If you don't have, then the answer is "probably yes, but it will take 6-9 months).

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion - I've actually created a similar set of object models irrespective of the fields that Sabre returns by parsing out native Sabre responses via the simple `SabreCommandLLSRQ` API.

My biggest issue right now is understanding the complexity of the proxy classes created in C# and figuring out how to use those classes to properly format a request and handle a response. Since most of the APIs I want to consume are so complicated I can't seem to get any of them to work (aside from the simple ones like `CreateSession`)